# jq query format csv export

Tags: json, linux, bash, csv, jq

I have a script bash with JQ, but do not know how to perform the query to get the following result:

conversationId(1),participantId(1),participantName(1),sessionId(1)
conversationId(1),participantId(2),participantName(2),sessionId(2)
conversationId(1),participantId(3),participantName(3),sessionId(3)
conversationId(2),participantId(4),participantName(4),sessionId(4)
.
.
.
conversationId(n),participantId(n),participantName(n),sessionId(n)

my file: data.json

```
{
    "conversations": [
        {
            "conversationId": "cxx-cccc-4444-9999-b11111111",
            "conversationStart": "2016-06-5T00:10:15.412Z",
            "conversationEnd": "2016-06-5T00:11:19.447Z",
            "participants": [
                {
                    "participantId": "2aaaa-1555-4590-99aa-4yyyyyyy",
                    "userId": "91111-7rrrr-4000-aqaa-23232323",
                    "purpose": "user",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "mediaType": "voice",
                            "sessionId": "1111111-aaaa-4009-9000-488888",
                            "ani": "sip:user+localhost.com@localhost",
                            "direction": "outbound",
                            "dnis": "tel:+1111110000",
                            "edgeId": "e3e3e3-4ª4q-4b4b-9792-95959595",
                            "segments": [
                                {
                             "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:10:15.412Z",
                             "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:10:10.485Z",
                            "segmentType": "contacting",
                                    "conference": false
                                },
                                {
                             "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:10:10.485Z",
                             "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:10:10.522Z",
                              "segmentType": "dialing",
                               "conference": false
                                },
                                {
                              "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:20:10.522Z",
                              "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:11:09.436Z",
                              "disconnectType": "client",
                               "segmentType": "interact",
                                "conference": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                 "participantId": "e9e9e9-d777-4a4a-8989-aeaeaeaeae",
                    "participantName": "Namek, Sayayin",
                    "purpose": "ivr",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "mediaType": "voice",
                           "sessionId": "262626-6000-4cdd-a511-fafafafa",
                           "ani": "sip:goku%localhost.com@localhost",
                           "direction": "inbound",
                          "edgeId": "e3e3e3e3-4abc-4abc-9700-95959595",
                            "remoteNameDisplayable": "Namek, Sayayin",
                            "segments": [
                                {
                              "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:10:10.510Z",
                              "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:10:10.521Z",
                              "segmentType": "system",
                                    "conference": false
                                },
                                {
                             "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:10:20.521Z",
                             "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:11:39.447Z",
                              "disconnectType": "peer",
                                    "segmentType": "ivr",
                                    "conference": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "conversationId": "09090909-6b60-8888-xxxx-9yyyyyyyy",
            "conversationStart": "2016-06-15T00:11:38.867Z",
            "conversationEnd": "2016-06-15T01:54:55.744Z",
            "participants": [
                {
                    "participantId": "xxxc-cccc1-4123-7777-343434343e",
                    "userId": "9qwer-7zxc-40df-aghj-2323232323",
                    "purpose": "user",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "mediaType": "voice",
                            "sessionId": "101010-0faz-4xxx-yyyy-4419441",
                            "ani": "sip:goku+localhost.com@localhost",
                            "direction": "outbound",
                            "dnis": "tel:+11112222333",
                            "edgeId": "nenene1-qwer-tyui-9000-9595gggh",
                            "segments": [
                               {
                              "segmentStart": "2016-06-15T00:11:18.867Z",
                              "segmentEnd": "2016-06-15T00:11:42.637Z",
                              "segmentType": "contacting",
                                "conference": false
                                }
                                ]
                        } ]
                } ]
        } ]
}
```

my query jq:

> jq . '{conversationId: .conversations[].conversationId, 
>   participantId:
>   .conversations[].participants[].participantId,participantName:
>   .conversations[].participants[].participantName} |  join(",")'

but the fields conversationId and participantName are repeated several times ...

Comment: Some participants do not have a name.

Comment: apologies, apparently it was not formatted as I should have already corrected it, I hope you can guide me

Comment: `jq` has **built-in** CSV support; see `@csv`. If you try to use `join` to emulate it, then the corner cases (around quoting, fields with literal commas or quotes in them, etc) will be wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your input, the following filter:

```
.conversations[]
| [.conversationId]
  + (.participants[] | [.participantId, .participantName])
```

produces:

```
[
  "cxx-cccc-4444-9999-b11111111",
  "2aaaa-1555-4590-99aa-4yyyyyyy",
  null
]
[
  "cxx-cccc-4444-9999-b11111111",
  "e9e9e9-d777-4a4a-8989-aeaeaeaeae",
  "Namek, Sayayin"
]
[
  "09090909-6b60-8888-xxxx-9yyyyyyyy",
  "xxxc-cccc1-4123-7777-343434343e",
  null
]
```

### Variant

Notice that the above filter does not use any jq variables.  Sometimes it is helpful to introduce them, so the following variant may be of interest:

```
.conversations[]
| (.participants | range(0;length)) as $j
| [.conversationId]
  + (.participants[$j] | [.participantId, .participantName])
```

With the help of the jq manual, you should be able to take it from here.

### Addendum

> ParticipantId(1),sessionId(1),mediaType(1),sessionId(1),ani(1),dnis(1)

I'm not quite sure why you would want `sessionsId` twice, but the following corresponds to your second request:

```
.conversations[].participants[]
| [.participantId] +
   (.sessions[] | [.sessionId, .mediaType, .sessionId, .ani, .dnis])
```

Comment: hi @peak one question if I wanted to get to 'sessions' and keep 'participantId' as initial field.... for example: 

ParticipantId(1),sessionId(1),mediaType(1),sessionId(1),ani(1),dnis(1)  .....

***I owe you my life.....***